# IOS secure enclave key storage for Safari Browser

Tags: ios, safari, keystore, x509, enclave

on my iPhone (IOS 14.8.1), I need to use the secure enclave to store my identity certificate’s private keys for the Safari browser so when I access an SSL protected site with my client certificate, the private keys are stored in the secure enclave.

I have tried the following ways below, but cannot find a way to have the private key generated in the secure enclave so that the Safari Browser can use it.

Try 1: Emailed a PCKS#12 filed, opened and installed. The problem is the private key is not generated in secure enclave and IOS prevents import of private key into secure enclave.

Try 2: I wrote an IOS app to generate a key in the secure enclave. The problem is I cannot share the keystore I created with my app with the Safari browser. So even though my app can access the key in the secure enclave, the safari browser cannot.

Try 3: I used the apple configurator to create the keys and install certificate using SCEP. The problem is, this does not generate the private key in the secure enclave.

Is it even possible to have the Safari Browser use the secure enclave to store the identity certificate? If so, could you please share some ideas of how can be achieved?

Thank you very much for any guidance or thoughts you may share. Have a wonderful day coding!

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to access the secure enclave from the browser for arbitrary operations. At the time of this writing, the only access of the enclave by the browser is for Webauthn and that interface is restricted to performing an authentication ceremony.